# Yammer attachments - how do I use the pending_attachments call?

Tags: c#, rest, yammer

I am working with the Yammer API and I want to be able to add files to new posts created through my application. This appears to be done through the `api/pending_attachments` call, but the [documentation is a little sketchy](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/pending_attachments) and doesn't really make it clear what the `pending_attachments` call is expecting - it wants an `attachment` property but it's entirely unclear what that means - is it the *file?* Is it the *file name?* In most cases I can't make the test on that page do anything other than fail with a 500 error, which is less than encouraging, but if I post a file chunk in Base64 Encoded format, it does fail in a way that tells me the request is too large. If I do only have a single field how do I tell Yammer what file the chunks I am uploading belong to so it can relate them?

From [this post](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/uploading-file-attachments-to-yammer/) it seems that there is a special secret and entirely unpublicised upload URL that one has to send the files to, but the upload process there seems like it might not work with chunked uploads which is what I'm currently using ( although that could be changed if necessary ) and the whole thing is very confusing.

I'm not using a specific library in this case, just interacting with the service that Yammer presents. I'm working from C#, but my question is about the Yammer API, so I'm not too worried about the language side of things.

What do I need to do in order to successfully upload pending attachments directly to Yammer?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Pending_attachments is not the correct endpoint to upload files to Yammer Post.

Steps Successfully Create a Yammer Post with attachments

1. Create Yammer Post using [this endpoint](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post) and store the thread_id from response.messages.thread_id from response json
2. Upload the attachment using [this endpoint](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/upload-files-into-yammer-groups) by sending a `multipart/form-data` formatted data.

Comment: I can't speak for the accuracy of this since I'm not working with Yammer any more, but  it looks like the API has moved forward a few versions since I asked this, so for modern users this is probably an improvement.

Comment: @glenatron Yes, API is improved over time. But still there is lot of scope for improvement. 
Feel free to mark this as an answer, if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was that you have to be sending a `multipart/form-data` formatted request in exactly the correct format, which in my case coming from a server-side application meant building everything up in to a byte array and sending it through with the standard format.

[The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload) show how to use a standard `HttpClient` approach to this.